Is it possible to consolidate Java logging?
I have a small Spring app that uses a few external libraries. Of these,
two in particular use:

library1.jar uses SLF4J.
library2.jar uses java.util.logging.

My application currently uses Log4J2, but I can change this if needed.
Now, when running the app the log file shows different log lines with different formats, depending if it's using java.util.logging or Log4J2.
I've read that SLF4J and/or Apache Commons Logging can somehow "consolidate" all logging into a single format. Is this actually possible?

The library jul-to-slf4j should resolve this. It lets you redirect java.util.logging logs to SLF4J. You could check this out https://medium.com/@a.petrivskyy/using-java-util-logging-and-slf4j-together-e7f2ee1d712b

It boggles my mind that nearly everyone is staunchly against using java.util.logging.  Java SE has far higher quality standards than third party offerings.

Yes this is possible. You can define a GlobalRequestLoggingAdvice class And define your own stratedgy over there.
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Aspect
public class GlobalRequestLoggingAdvice {  

     @Before("execution(* com.example.controller.*.*.*(..))")
        public void beforeWebMethodExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
            Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
            String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
            String className = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getName();
            if (checkLogAcceptance(args, className, methodName)) {
    
                //define your log generation logic here with required parameters
                //Define a custom pojo class with necessary parameters and build the desired log pattern here
            }
        }
}

Create a log4j2.xml in your src/main/resource directory define your common pattern over there
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss aaa} %5p [%c] - %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingFileAppender" fileName="${user.home}/log/hcs.log"
                                 filePattern="${user.home}/log/hcs.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="your application package name here (com.example.app)" level="DEBUG" additivity="FALSE">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Finally Replace any direct calls to java.util.logging or any other logging frameworks with SLF4J. For example:
public class MyController{

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

    public void testLog() {
        logger.info("This is a test log message");
    }

}

Please ensure you used the proper logging dependencies in your pom.xml file.
